# How to get $_FILES data via ajax in same format as via pure PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

I've working upload script. Only thing I need to edit is format of $_FILES array.

My HTML

```
<input id="upload_dialog" name="file[]" type="file" multiple>
```

My Javascript

```
<script>
    $('#upload_dialog').on('change', function(event) {
      var form = new FormData();
      $.each(event.target.files, function(key, value) {
        form.append(key, value);
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: 'url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        done: function(data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);

      });
    });
</script>
```

This array I will get by uploading files via ajax.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "ps-logo.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(23) "/home/www/tmp/phpMBu4TE"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(24722)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "tnk-logo.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(23) "/home/www/tmp/php9yPGpf"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(23748)
  }
}
```

But I would need this type of array, which I usually get if I submit upload form only via pure PHP.

```
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "tnk-logo.png"
      [1]=>
      string(11) "ps-logo.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "image/png"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) "/home/www/tmp/phpWGezym"
      [1]=>
      string(23) "/home/www/tmp/phpIqOpKY"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(23748)
      [1]=>
      int(24722)
    }
  }
}
```

**Is there any simple way how to send data via ajax to get this type of array?**

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript Solution**

Instead of adding the files as elements of a new form, create the `FormData` instance using the form that the input is already inside of.

```
$('#upload_dialog').on('change', function(event) {
    var input = event.target,
        form = input.form,
        data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        done: function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**My original not-as-good PHP solution**

To have PHP handle both ways that the files might be submitted, you could do something like this to convert it to the format you want if it isn't already in that format:

```
function maybe_ajax_files($field) {
    // If $_FILES is empty or it's already got the field we need,
    // just use it as-is.
    if (empty($_FILES) || isset($_FILES[$field])) {
        return $_FILES;
    }

    // Otherwise, regroup them...
    $regrouped = array();
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        foreach ($file as $key => $val) {
            if (!isset($regrouped[$key])) {
                $regrouped[$key] = array();
            }
            $regrouped[$key][] = $val;
        }
    }

    // Then assign that array to the desired field in a new array.
    $files = array();
    $files[$field] = $regrouped;
    return $files;
}

// 'file' is the name of the field in your example:
// <input id="upload_dialog" name="file[]" type="file" multiple>
$files = maybe_ajax_files('file');
```

Comment: Sure, that was at the top of my head as a solution, but I would like to avoid this and solve it in JS, if it would be possible. If not, I will have to do it the way you described.

Comment: Edited my answer with a better, JavaScript-only answer.

Comment: Yes, that's excactly what I need. Last thing I need to solve is, that I have more than one file input in form together and I need to send via ajax data only from the one, which was selected. Now, all file-inputs are sending to php and some of them are empty. Is there a way how to remove these empty file-inputs before sending to php?

Comment: Depending on your situation, you could just leave 'em. There's not much overhead in sending empty fields. But you could, instead of instantiating the FormData with the whole form, create an empty one like you originally did, read the name of the one input that changed, and append that field alone to the FormData.

Comment: I've marked empty fields as "disabled" while sending, that works for me. In future I will probably implement your idea, it seems more clear for me. Anyway, thanks a lot for a help.